# Is there a better way than parsing a stack trace to get the currently running or calling method?

Tags: java, methods, java-threads

The historical method has been to parse the output of `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`, but there have been so many changes since Java 8 (like method handles) that I wasn't sure if a better way now exists.

If it helps, my specific goal here is to act based on annotations on the calling method, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java 9 introduced the StackWalker API

It's best practice to store your StackWalker instance in a private static final field:

```
class SomeClass {
    private static final StackWalker SW = StackWalker.getInstance(StackWalker.Option.RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE);

    public someCallerSensitiveMethod() {
        Class<?> caller = SW.getCallerClass();
        // Do something with it, like check it's annotations
    }
}
```